# Ubuntu 64bit 11.10 + Kinect

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS and trying to run RBGDSLAM using Kinect. There was some issues installing drivers (such as changing openjava7 to sun java6 for compiler)
lsusb does not show camera and audio.

When I connect usb and run command

roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch

---output

INFO] [1329185066.431671629]: [/openni_node1] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected

-------output for lsusb

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 003 Device 010: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:58e5 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c517 Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser

Bus 003 Device 011: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor

I am not sure why it is only showing the Motor on usb port.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27559/ubuntu-64bit-11.10-+-kinect/) by [Empty](https://answers.ros.org/users/1787/empty/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you might not have the 12V power supplied to the Kinect.  There should be three Microsoft devices listed.

See [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/3076/kinect-no-devices-connected-on-openni_nodelaunch)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1